# Does Java have an equivalent to Python's list.sorted() method for ArrayLists?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, overloading

I know I can call `Collections.sort()` on an `ArrayList` in Java, but I am currently trying to overload a constructor, and in the second one I would like to call the first constructor. However, I want to pass a sorted list as one of the arguments, but Java won't let me call `this()` after sorting the list - it requires `this()` to be the first line. I could just put `Collections.sort(myList)` in the constructor, but I don't know if this method returns the sorted list, but ideally I would like to return the sorted list without mutating the original.

Here is my code (for a period such as you would find in a school or university), including the error:

```
public class Period {

    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime start;
    // duration in seconds
    private int duration;
    private Lecturer lecturer;
    private ArrayList<Demonstrator> dems;
    private ArrayList<Skill> skills;
    
    public Period(String name, LocalDateTime start, int duration, Lecturer lecturer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.start = start;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.lecturer = lecturer;
        this.dems = new ArrayList<>();
        this.skills = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public Period(String name, ArrayList<AvailBlock> blocks, Lecturer lecturer) {
        // this line is illegal, but shows you what I'm trying to do.
        Collections.sort(blocks);
        this(name, blocks.get(0).getStart(), ( blocks.size() * AvailBlock.LENGTH ), lecturer);
    }
    ...
}
```

The `AvailBlock` class has a start time as a `LocalDateTime` object, and a fixed duration (currently 15 minutes). I am trying to have the option of creating a period with a duration in seconds, or just passing in a list of `AvailBlock` objects and letting it figure out when the period starts and how long it should be.

Here is the beginning of the `AvailBlock` class:

```
public class AvailBlock implements Comparable {
    
    // the start time of the slot
    private LocalDateTime start;
    // Length of slots in seconds
    public static final int LENGTH = 900;
    
    public AvailBlock(LocalDateTime start) {
        this.start = start;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you find yourself doing nontrivial work in a constructor, you might consider making it a static factory method instead. Generally, when I call a constructor, I expect it to do nothing more than assign some fields, do some basic error checking, and the absolute minimum amount of work necessary to get a working instance of the class back to me.

Comment: Thank you. I have since created a third constructor but it is looking a little messy - I will look into static factory method as I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo "Create a managed, sorted copy of this list of objects" is a perfectly ordinary task for some manager object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Make a static factory method

As [commented by Mayolo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68273464/does-java-have-an-equivalent-to-pythons-list-sorted-method-for-arraylists/68274908#comment120664055_68273464), I would do this work in a static method rather than in a constructor. Best to keep constructors utterly simple.

Furthermore, the first line of a constructor must be an implicit or explicit call to the super constructor. So we cannot have code such as your call to `Collections.sort` before making a call to `this( … )`. This must be the problem to which you alluded in saying "// this line is illegal, but shows you what I'm trying to do.". This Java language requirement of first-line-as-super-constructor-call is another reason to use a static factory method to solve your problem.

I would name the method `from` per the [*java.time* naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html).

```java
public static Period from ( … )
{
    …
    return new Period( … ) ;
}
```

Usage:

```
Period p = Period.from( … ) ;
```

## Make a copy of the input list

You said:

> I could just put Collections.sort(myList) in the constructor, but I don't know if this method returns the sorted list, but ideally I would like to return the sorted list without mutating the original.

Make a copy of the list before sorting. Then you avoid mutating the original.

To make a shallow copy, you can **pass any `Collection` to the constructor of `ArrayList`**.

Also, notice that since we making a copy and then sorting, your factory method can take any kind of [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html), not just [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html). Actually, any kind of [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html) can be accepted.

```java
public static Period from ( String name, Collection< AvailBlock > blocks, Lecturer lecturer )
{
    ArrayList< AvailBlock > blocksSorted = new ArrayList<>( blocks ) ;
    Collections.sort( blocksSorted );
    return new Period( name, blocksSorted.get(0).getStart(), ( blocks.size() * AvailBlock.LENGTH ), lecturer ) ;
}
```

### `List.copyOf`

If you want a unmodifiable copy, pass your list to [`List.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)).

---

### `record`

By the way, you might find handy the [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature added to [Java 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_16).

A record is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. You merely need declare the type and name of each member field. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

A record can carry a static factory method as we need here in our solution.

Comment: Thanks very much for the in-depth reply. So, if I have something like ```x = new ArrayList<SomeType>(someCollection);``` that would be like python's ```x = someCollection.copy()```? A shallow copy is exactly what I want in this case. That record thing sounds very useful, I'll look into that.

Comment: @Donagh I do not know Python. But yes, passing a `Collection` such as a `List` to the constructor of `ArrayList` produces a new `List`/`Collection` containing references to all the same objects in the original. For example, if you start with a list of ten references to ten objects, after passing to the constructor, you’ll have two lists, each with ten references for a total of twenty references, but the same original ten objects, each of the ten objects being referenced twice, once from each list (original list, and new list).

Comment: thanks. Yes, that's what Python's `.copy()` method does - I can't remember how deep copy is done in Python, but that's not what I was looking for anyway. Thanks for the clarification (I've actually always wondered if `new ArrayList<>()` can take an argument, so now I know!).

Answer (score 0):

I'd echo other's comments about not doing too much in a constructor. However, if you *do* want to sort inline without mutating the original list, streams would seem the most natural way to go. You can quite easily do the sorting without mutating the original list:

```
blocks.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList())
```

(...which will return a sorted list which you can use either inline, or assign to a variable.)

Comment: Good to know, but I feel like the previous suggestions might be a bit more readable.